# copy a file from one dir to another dir

Tags: php

How i can copy one file from one directory to another directory using php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

- [`copy`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) — Copies file

Example from Manual:

```
$file = 'example.txt';
$newfile = 'example.txt.bak';

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`rename()`](http://www.php.net/rename).

```
rename ("/var/www/files/file.txt", "/var/www/sites/file.txt");
```

Comment: it is working fine.But it is deleted from the source i Want it in the source also

Comment: @THOmas you are asking to *move* it in the question title, and *copy* in the question body... To copy it, use [`copy()`](http://www.php.net/copy)

Answer (score 3):

```
rename('path/to/file/file.ext', 'path2/to2/file2/file.ext');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are moving a file just uploaded, use http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php instead of rename(). It gives you some added security.