# How to Copy the File from one Folder to another

Tags: php, email

Hi i am using libmail to send mails. In File Attachment  Php File Upload is not working Because libmail attachment function only focus the local path . So It is possible to copy a file from one folder to  another. Is It Possible Please Guide me. Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [copy a file from one dir to another dir](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616602/copy-a-file-from-one-dir-to-another-dir)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `copy()` in php.

```
copy('path/to/original/text.txt', 'path/to/destination/text.txt');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

`rename()` is for actually renaming a file.

Answer (score -1):

```
rename('path/to/file/file.ext', 'path2/to2/file2/file.ext');
```

Comment: actually this syntax move the file, use the copy() function instead (same parameters: http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)