# copy content file php another file php with replace title

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [copy a file from one dir to another dir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616602/copy-a-file-from-one-dir-to-another-dir)

I would like to copy from local content from a php file and copy it to another file before copying php and make a specific content replace a php file.
I do the following:

```
chmod ('../archivo.php',0777);
$archivo= fopen("../archivo.php" , "r"); 
$get=file_get_contents($archivo);
$nuevoarchivo = fopen('../new-archivo.php', "w+");
fwrite($nuevoarchivo,$get);
fclose($nuevoarchivo);
```

But do not copy anything How could I?
Thank you very much and hug.

Comment: has been chance, I have not duplicated anything, we will have written at the same time. I can not ask a question to attack me. Can you please take my negative vote. And no wonder more. For once I get asked a negative.

Comment: The -1 is for not doing research. How to copy a file is easy to google and has been answered multiple times before. Please do research before asking questions like you agreed to do in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Comment: that question is not the same as the same and also the response. Parce reminding that you are willing to put negatives.

Comment: I also learned more by Aziz response. I appreciate you purge the negative point

Comment: you asked how to copy a file before modifying it and the linked dupe shows how to do that. So how are you asking something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix `file_get_contents` and `fopen`.

```
// Read file content
$file_content = file_get_contents('../archivo.php');

// do the replacements, modifications, etc. on $file_content
// This is just an example
$file_content = str_replace('old_title', 'new_title', $file_content);

// write the content to a new file
file_put_contents('../new-archivo.php', $file_content);
```

Also Can you be more specific about what you want to replace?

Comment: Thank you very much! I really have been a great help.
Replace the meta title with

Comment: $header = preg_replace('/(<title>[\s\n]*)/is', "$1$metatitle", $get);